# Routing with Dashes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an app with ASP.NET MVC 5. I want my app to have a route that looks like the following:

```
http://www.myserver.com/my-category
```

Please notice how the route has a dash (-) in it. I currently have a controller named MyCategoryController. It is defined like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("my-category")]
    public class MyCategoryController : Controller
    {
        // GET: List
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The view is located in `/Views/My-Category/Index.cshtm`l. When I try to access `http://www.myserver.com/my-category` in the browser, I get an error that says:

> The resource cannot be found.

I set a breakpoint and I noticed that the breakpoint is not hit. I then enter http://www.myserver.com/mycategory into the browser, and I get an error that says:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>
> ~/Views/mycategory/Index.cshtml
> ~/Views/mycategory/Index.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

How do I setup my ASP.NET MVC so that
a) I can visit `http://www.myserver.com/my-category` and
b) Load the view from `/Views/my-category/Index.cshtml`

Comment: Why not having the directory called "MyCategory" without dashes?

Comment: Indeed, why do you care what the folder name is where your views are stored.

Comment: use an underscore if it is really bothering you that the folder does not match the route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to name the views folder like the controller not like the route.

So `/Views/MyCategory/Index.cshtml` and not `/Views/My-Category/Index.cshtml`.

If you, for a reason I can't imagine why, want it to be `/Views/My-Category/Index.cshtml` you need to "fully quallify the view":

```
return View("~/Views/My-Category/Index.cshtml");
```

About the route with the dash: I am not using attribute based routing so I can only guess:
Did you add the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in your `RegisterRoutes` method?
Because `http://www.myserver.com/mycategory` is routed by the default `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` route...

Comment: I would actually reccomend underscore instead

Comment: @ScottSelby: I wouldn't recommend it at all, but if the OP "really wants to" I wanted to show how it could be done...

Comment: lol - I meant , assuming from the fact that he even made a question , that he was stuck on not omitting the "-" , so I was saying if that is the case , then I would reccommend the underscore because it is allowed